# Solving nonlinear differential equation by substitution

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Has someone an idea, how to get a differential equation for $\Phi (x) := ||y(x)||^2$ from this nonlinear ODE?

$\begin{pmatrix}
y'_1(x)\\ y'_2(x)
\end{pmatrix}
=
\begin{pmatrix}
0 & -1\\ 1 & 0
\end{pmatrix}
\begin{pmatrix}
y_1(x)\\ y_2(x)
\end{pmatrix}
+ \epsilon||y(x)||^2
\begin{pmatrix}
y_1(x)\\ y_2(x)
\end{pmatrix}$?

Thanks & have a nice day!

Comment: Multiply by $(y_1, y_2)$ and use the product rule to re-write the left hand side.

Comment: Yeah, thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Or simply switch to polar coordinates
$$x = r \cos{\theta}$$
$$y = r \sin{\theta}$$

Then your equation simplifies significantly and you get the equation that you need plus you solve the system completely.